# How to bind a 2D layered texture to pitched linear memory in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I have a CUDA compute capability 2.0 graphics card and the CUDA Toolkit 4.0, and I want to make use of the new tex2DLayered texture lookup function. However, the size of my array (1280 x 960 x 200 layers, unsigned short) is too large to allocate a cuda3DArray of this size, so I want to bind pitched linear memory to the texture instead. However, I cannot find any description of how to do this in any of the CUDA documentation or SDK examples, including the Simple Layered Texture example, which uses a cuda3DArray rather than linear memory. I've also searched online, without success.

Can anyone either provide the code necessary to bind the texture, or a link to some instructions on how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe layered textures work with linear memory, only with a cuda array.

Comment: Is that somewhere in the documentation?

Comment: Well, the documentation only mentions cudaArrays, not pitched linear memory. Usually if linear memory is not explicitly listed, it is safe to assume that it isn't supported. The hardware implementation is probably the same as DX10 texture arrays, and that is implemented using space filling rather than linear memory AFIAK.

Comment: Found it. Thanks. Section 3.2.10.1.5 of the CUDA C Programming Guide v4.0 states that:
"A layered texture can only be bound to a CUDA array created by calling cudaMalloc3DArray() with the cudaArrayLayered flag (and a height of zero for one-dimensional layered texture)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section 3.2.10.1.5 of the CUDA C Programming Guide v4.0 states that:

> "A layered texture can only be bound to a CUDA array created by calling cudaMalloc3DArray() with the cudaArrayLayered flag (and a height of zero for one-dimensional layered texture)."